# Error when querying PostgreSQL using range operators

Tags: postgresql, python-2.7, psycopg2

I am trying to query a postgresql (v 9.3.6) table with a tstzrange to determine if a given timestamp exists within the table defined as

```
CREATE TABLE sensor(
  id serial,
  hostname varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  ip varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  period tstzrange NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY(id),
  EXCLUDE USING gist (hostname WITH =, period with &&)
);
```

I am using psycopg2 and when I try the query:

```
sql = "SELECT id FROM sensor WHERE %s <@ period;"
cursor.execute(sql,(isotimestamp,))
```

I get the error

```
psycopg2.DataError: malformed range literal: 
...
DETAIL:  Missing left parenthesis or bracket.
```

I've tried various type castings to no avail.

I've managed a workaround using the following query:

```
sql = "SELECT * FROM sensor WHERE %s BETWEEN lower(period) AND upper(period);"
```

but would like to know why I am having problem with the range operators. Is it my code or psycopg2 or what?

Any help is appreciated.

EDIT 1:
In response to the comments, I have attempted the same query on a simple 1-row table in postgresql like below

```
=> select * from sensor;
session_id | hostname |    ip     |                              period                               
------------+----------+-----------+-------------------------------------------------------------------
1 | bob    | 127.0.0.1 | ["2015-02-08 19:26:42.032637+00","2015-02-08 19:27:28.562341+00")
```

(1 row)

Now by using the "@>" operator I get the following error:

```
=> select * from sensor where period @> '2015-02-08 19:26:43.04+00';
ERROR:  malformed range literal: "2015-02-08 19:26:43.04+00"
LINE 1: select * from sensor where period @> '2015-02-08 19:26:42.03...
```

Which appears to be the same as the psycopg2 error, a malformed range literal, so I thought I would try typecasting to timestamp as below

```
=> select * from sensor where sensor.period @> '2015-02-08  19:26:42.032637+00'::timestamptz;
session_id | hostname |    ip     |                              period
```

------------+----------+-----------+-------------------------------------------------------------------
    1 | feral    | 127.0.0.1 | ["2015-02-08 19:26:42.032637+00","2015-02-08 19:27:28.562341+00")

So it appears that it is my mistake, the literal has to be typecast or it is assumed to be a range. Using psycopg2, the query can be executed with:

```
sql="select * from sensor where period @> %s::timestamptz"
```

Comment: Could you show us the real query that has been sent to the database? It looks like psycopg2 doesn't work correct with ranges.

Comment: What about the trailing comma in `cursor.execute(sql,(isotimestamp,))`?

Comment: Thanks Frank, just trying to answer your comment I was able to get it working

Comment: Erwin, (1) is an int as in type((1)) = <type 'int'> and (1,) is a tuple. pscyopg2 requires a tuple